# If $a\le b$ and $l,m\ge 1$, then $|l+e^{i\gamma}|(a+mb)\leq (l+m)|a+e^{i\gamma}b|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $a, b$ be  any two positive real numbers such that $a\geq lb$ where $l\geq 1.$ Suppose $\gamma $ is any real such that $0\leq \gamma\leq 2\pi.$  Is it true that 
$$|l+e^{i\gamma}|(a+mb)\leq (l+m)|a+e^{i\gamma}b|$$ for any $m\geq 1?$

Comment: I removed the number-theory tag. I don't see any number-theoretical content here. If you agree, you might want to change the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to:
$$\frac{a+mb}{l+m}\leq\left|\frac{a+e^{i\gamma}b}{l+e^{i\gamma}}\right|$$
or to:
$$b+\frac{a-bl}{l+m}\leq \left|b+\frac{a-bl}{l+e^{i\gamma}}\right| $$
that follows from:
$$b+\frac{a-bl}{l+m}\leq b+\frac{a-bl}{l+1}\leq\left|b+\frac{a-bl}{l+e^{i\gamma}}\right|. $$